# Is there a whatsapp open URL for Direct calling like to send media and text in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, call, whatsapp

I am trying to implemented a link from IOS application to open whatsapp and start chat, send media and call.

so far with below link I am able to achieve the first two, is there any open URL to make a direct call using whatsapp from my app button click.

[https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013][1]

Something like below example

`NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://call:+6511112222?"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Whatsapp doesnot have a URLScheme for direct calling. They only have URL schemes for chat.

May be in the future they might add it. Keep checking the WhatsApp FAQ section.

Incase for power users when WhatsApp new version is added we can check the info.plist of whatsapp using iExplorer software. The plist contains the URLscheme that is registered. If they have added for calls we can capture it.